# Replacing html string with Python

Tags: python, html

I have been struggle with this for a while. I have been trying to modify html based on the content of a folder with Python. But whenever I try to modify it the whole thing would crash. I am new with Python as well as HTML. I made a class that would load the HTML files and some sub functions to modify it:

```
class htmlfile(object):
    data = ""

    def openHTML(self, name="main.html"):
        # f = open('main.html')
        # for line in f:
        #     #print line.replace("Thinominal", "")
        with open(name) as myHtml:
            data = myHtml.read()
        self.data = data

    # def __repr__(self):
    #     return "Test()"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.data

    def replace(self, location, insert):
        self.data.replace(location, insert)

    def makeBackground(self, location):
        self.data.replace("backgrounds: [", "backgrounds: ["+ getPhotos2())
```

and another function to get list of "content"/ photos from a folder and return strings that would later be insert into the HTML:

```
def getPhotos2(dir, type="jpg"):  # get Photo from a directory with a chosen Type. Default Type = jpg
    os.chdir(dir)
    data = ""
    for file in glob.glob("*.%s" % type):
        data = data + "{src: '%s/%s', fade: 2000}," % (dir, file)
    return data
```

but whenever I run this, this error show up:

```
self = <__main__.htmlfile object>, self.data = '<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html lang="en">\r\n<head>\r\n <...\n</script>\r\n<!-- /Navbar-->\r\n\r\n</body>\r\n\r\n</html>', self.data.toString undefined, global getPhotos2 = <function getPhotos2>
```

I don't understand. Isn't python is opening the html as a string/text file? and printing it?. Like if you were to do just:

```
html = """ <head>Hello World</head>"""
print html
```

this would work. you could also do :

`html.replace("hello world", "BYE BYE")` too. So what did I do wrong here? Am I missing something? Any Advice would be appreciated.

This is how i called the function:

```
htmlfile = htmlfile()
htmlfile.openHTML()
htmlfile.makeBackgroud("background")
print htmlfile
```

I would like to just able to replace any part of the Html as though it was a STRING. for example:
This is manually populated:

```
backgrounds: [
        {src: './img/nature1.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/bw1.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/portrait1.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/portrait5.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/portrait2.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/portrait3.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/portrait4.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/forest.jpg', fade: 2000}

    ]
```

with the "makeBackground" function, it would generate those strings and Insert it within the HTML. If i have a folder call background that contain coolImg.jpg. THe make background will generate: `{src: './img/coolImg.jpg', fade: 2000}` and insert it into the "background:" section. Result in:

```
backgrounds: [
        {src: './img/nature1.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/bw1.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/portrait1.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/portrait5.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/portrait2.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/portrait3.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/portrait4.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './img/forest.jpg', fade: 2000},
        {src: './background/coolImg.jpg', fade: 2000} <- THIS HERE
    ]
```

Comment: You haven't shown any error. Where we you calling the functions? What are you doing with the result?

Comment: Let us know how are you calling the functions and what exactly you would like to achieve. An example would help.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the code with how i called the function.

Comment: makeBackground, In general, is just an overcomplicated STR.Replace Function().

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work now. It was mostly my fault for being a noob. I forgot to set the value of the replaced String to replace the Original String. Like this:

```
self.data = self.data.replace(oldstring, newstring)
```

the "self.data =" was missing.
I also forgot to give the same amount of parameter that my function is asking.

```
def getPhotos2(dir, type="jpg"):  # get Photo from a directory with a chosen Type. Default Type = jpg
os.chdir(dir)
data = ""
for file in glob.glob("*.%s" % type):
    data = data + "{src: '%s/%s', fade: 2000}," % (dir, file)
return data

print "Content-type: text/html\n"


# html class
class htmlfile(object):
data = ""

def openHTML(self, name="main.html"):
    with open(name) as myHtml:
        data = myHtml.read()
    self.data = data

def __str__(self):
    return self.data

def replace(self, location, insert):
    self.data = self.data.replace(location, insert)
def makeBackground(self, location):
    self.data = self.data.replace("backgrounds: [", "backgrounds: ["+ getPhotos2(location))


htmlfile = htmlfile()
htmlfile.openHTML()
htmlfile.makeBackground("photo")
print htmlfile
```

This work, If anyone can spot any mistake, feel free to tell me. Thank you all for trying to help ^^